# SWF file uploaded to server but not showing in embed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've embedded a .swf file into my code but it won't show up when tested. It plays directly from the source (http://pandadol.com/pics/sydneyedit/300x250.swf) but not from the HTML file.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<object data="http://pandadol.com/pics/sydneyedit/300x250.swf">
   <param name="movie" value="http://pandadol.com/pics/sydneyedit/300x250.swf">  
</object>

<object data="http://www.adobe.com/jp/events/cs3_web_edition_tour/swfs/perform.swf">
   <param name="movie" value="http://www.adobe.com/jp/events/cs3_web_edition_tour/swfs/perform.swf">  
</object>

</body>

</html>
```

I've put it here with a default one from Adobe just to see if it wasn't my flash player that was the problem, but it seems to show up fine.

There has to be something ridiculous I'm missing. If anyone has a clue I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`classid`, `codebase`, and `width` and `height` are both required attributes for an `<object>` tag. Also the `movie` parameter is required.

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

The code to use is:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="movie_name" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="movie_name.swf"/>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="movie_name.swf" width="550" height="400">
        <param name="movie" value="movie_name.swf"/>
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/>
        </a>
    </object>
</object>
```

Or:

```
<div id="myContent">
  <p>Alternative content</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0");
</script>
```